# What does the " \'" mean in splitting a command line?

Tags: c

```c
int parseline(const char *cmdline, char **argv)
{
    static char array[MAXLINE]; /* holds local copy of command line */
    char *buf = array;          /* ptr that traverses command line */
    char *delim;                /* points to first space delimiter */
    int argc;                   /* number of args */
    int bg;                     /* background job? */

    strcpy(buf, cmdline);
    buf[strlen(buf)-1] = ' ';  /* replace trailing '\n' with space */
    while (*buf && (*buf == ' ')) /* ignore leading spaces */
        buf++;

    /* Build the argv list */
    argc = 0;
    if (*buf == '\'') {
        buf++;
        delim = strchr(buf, '\'');
    }
    else {
        delim = strchr(buf, ' ');
    }

//...
}
```

The part I don't understand is `if (*buf == '\'')`.

What I know about this part is to split command line with a delimiter, and the latter one is space, then what the `\'` mean?

Comment: In a POSIX-ish shell, when you encounter an unescaped single quote, that starts a single-quoted string up until the next single quote — no characters in between have any special significance, not even backslash.  If you're in a double quoted string, the rules are different, but inside a double quoted string, single quotes are not special (but backslashes are, and so are `$` and back-tick (which is hard to get into a comment) and so on).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'\''` is an escaped single quote

see [here for more escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C#Table_of_escape_sequences)